# Remove Characters in a String in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a column u_manualdoc which contains the values are like this `CGY DR# 7405`. I want to remove the `CGY DR#`.
Here's the code:

```
select u_manualdoc, cardcode, cardname from ODLN
```

I want only the `7405` number. Thanks!

Comment: You should show us more data.

Comment: here are some data in u_manualdoc "CGY PST  - 58277" , "CGY RMC PST # 58083", "CGY DR # 7443, CSI # 1304", "PO# 0568 , 0570 CGY  DR# 7446". I want only a number. Thanks!

Comment: Your first data point has a hyphen instead of pound sign.  Are there any other separators besides hyphen and pound?

Comment: comma, I think. There's no pound sign here sir

Comment: please edit the question and update with the rules or logic that you wanted

Comment: EDIT YOUR QUESTION and add DDL, sample data and expected results.  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
--sample data you provided in comments
declare @tbl table(codes varchar(20))
insert into @tbl values
('CGY PST - 58277') , ('CGY RMC PST # 58083'), ('CGY DR # 7443'), ('CSI # 1304'), ('PO# 0568 , 0570'), ('CGY DR# 7446')

--actual query that you can apply to your table
select SUBSTRING(codes, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', codes), len(codes)) from @tbl
```

The key point here is to use `patindex`, which searches for a pattern and returns index where such pattern occur. I specified `%[0-9]%` which means that we search for any digit - it will return first occurrence of a digit. Now- since this would be our starting point to substring, we pass it to such function. Third parameter of `substring` is length. Since we want the rest of a string, `len` function makes sure that we get that :)

Applying to your naming:

```
select SUBSTRING(u_manualdoc, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', u_manualdoc), len(u_manualdoc)),
       cardcode,
       cardname
from ODLN
```

Comment: @sCom You are right, but from OP data I guess it's mistake and these are two different entries (`0570` is part of previous entry).

Comment: There should be a constant separator to extract , suppose if string is ' 0570 CGY-DR# 7446'  then it will fail, as it will give output as 'DR# 7446' rather than '7446'

Comment: There are some value that still has a character because others have the value like this ('PO# 0568 , 0570 CGY  DR# 7446'). Not all value has the same length. But the rest are only the numbers. Thanks @Evaldas Buinauskas

Answer (score 1):

You should use string functions charindex,len and substring to get it.
See the code below.

```
select SUBSTRING(u_manualdoc,CHARINDEX('#',u_manualdoc)+1,LEN(u_manualdoc)- CHARINDEX('#',u_manualdoc))
```

Comment: It won't work in case of `CGY PST - 58277`. Maybe you could use `patindex` with `%[#-]%` pattern.

Comment: '#' is a separator here, it will be there as you can see in values given by @shiela.  She want to extract from '#' not any other charecter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It remove the other but there are others are still have characters. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

In addition to the other answers, you can use this simple method:

```
select
    substring(
        u_manualdoc,
        len(u_manualdoc) - patindex('%[^0-9]%', reverse(u_manualdoc)) + 2,
        len(u_manualdoc)
    ),
    cardcode, cardname
from ODLN
```

In this example, [`patindex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) finds the first non-digit (as specified by `^[0-9]`) from the right side of the string, and then uses that as the starting point of the substring.

This will work on all of your sample strings (including 'PO# 0568 , 0570 CGY DR# 7446').

Or use [SQL Server Regex](http://eval-sql.net/sql-server-regex), which lets you use more powerful regular expressions within your queries.

Comment: There should be a constant separator to extract , suppose if string is ' 0570 CGY-DR# 7446'  then it will fail, as it will give output as 'DR# 7446' rather than '7446'

Comment: That is not correct @sCom. It returns `7446` for that string.

Comment: Exactly what i thought after coming back to this question! Brilliant solution :) +1

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(DirtyCol VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES('AB ABCDE # 123'), ('ABCDE# 123'), ('AB: ABC# 123 AB: ABC# 123'), ('AB#'), ('AB # 1 000 000'), ('AB # 1`234`567'), ('AB # (9)(876)(543)');
WITH tally
     AS (
     SELECT TOP (100) N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@spid)
     FROM sys.all_columns),
     data
     AS (
     SELECT DirtyCol,
            Col
     FROM @table
          CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
(
    SELECT C+''
    FROM
(
    SELECT N,
           SUBSTRING(DirtyCol, N, 1) C
    FROM tally
    WHERE N <= DATALENGTH(DirtyCol)
) [1]
    WHERE C BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
    ORDER BY N FOR XML PATH('')
)
) p(Col)
     WHERE p.Col IS NOT NULL)
     SELECT DirtyCol,
            CAST(Col AS INT) IntCol
     FROM data;
```

Comment: please format your code in order to be helpful to the OP